# Cordova geolocation plugin not firing at all in Ionic app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I’m building an app with Ionic v1.x (France), Angular 1.5.3, and Cordova 7.0.0

I want to use the geolocation plugin but it is not working.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation

When I run the app in the browser it works fine but when I try it on my Android device it does not work. It does not throw an error but it does not run the code either.

Service file:

```
  (function () {
    "use strict";

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myService', [
        '$cordovaGeolocation',
        '$ionicPlatform',
        function ($cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform) {

            var myService = {};

            myService.getLocation = function () {

                    console.log($cordovaGeolocation);

                    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                        console.log('ionic ready');
                        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition()
                        .then(function (position) {
                            console.log('position ', position);
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log('error ', error);
                        }).finally(function () {
                            console.log('made it here ');
                        });
                    });

            };

            return myService;
        }])
```

})();

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Softworks Self Service</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bday.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/xmas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-content-banner/dist/ionic.content.banner.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ion-floating-menu/dist/ion-floating-menu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>


    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Needed for Cordova/PhoneGap (will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
```

The controller just calls the service function.
I get to the point where it prints out ‘ionic ready’ but that’s it.

I do not get any errors. The code in the promises does not execute. The console statement before the $ionicReady prints out a function including getCurrentLocation.

I am hoping to use the error codes I get back to show a popup to the user to turn on permissions etc.

Comment: what does this return console.log($cordovaGeolocation);?

Comment: Can you please post the error that are you getting?

Comment: No errors. The code doesnt execute past the ionic ready log.

Comment: Where do you call myService.getLocation() ?

Comment: In my controller. It just calls the function like you wrote.

Comment: Your location is on and your app has permission to use it?

Comment: No but isnt that something that the get location function should be able to tell me in the error codes? I was hoping to use the error codes for showing a popup.